# Run Javascript on Woocommerce if page equals X and number of cart items equals Y

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, sweetalert

I am trying to run javascript (Sweet Alert) on Woocommerce archive shop pages to execute only if there are 5 items in the cart & the page is equal to 'url/leanshop/'.

My add to cart functionality is using AJAX. The below code, sort of works...but I can't get it to trigger for the above conditions. It currently only triggers each time a product is added to the cart via AJAX.

**My code so far:**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'items_in_cart_trigger' );
function items_in_cart_trigger() {

        global $woocommerce;
        // Set the minimum number of products in cart
        $maximum_num_products = 5;
        // Get the Cart's total number of products
        $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;

        // Compare values and if required amount of items in cart, display popup.
        if( $cart_num_products == $maximum_num_products && is_page( '/leanshop/' ) ) {

    ?>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                    // Test output on JS console
                    console.log('added_to_cart'); 
                    // Call Sweet Alert PopUp Here
                  swal(
                    'You added all the items!',
                    'Proceed to checkout?',
                    'success')
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The Javascript works with the following is_page() IF statement. So the problem is the logic above where I am trying to count the amount of items in the shopping cart and see if they are equal to a value, *whilst* on the shop archive page. Can anyone suggest the correct Woocommerce code logic in order to do so?

```
if( is_page('leanshop'))    {
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if( $cart_num_products === $maximum_num_products && is_page( '/leanshop/' ) ) {
```

To [test for equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), use triple equals (when same type) or double equals (when want to coerce type, but beware).

Comment: Sorry, typo in code above, it was double equals...tried it with triple equals, but still not working.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with WooCommerce, but as a guess perhaps the value isn't initialized until first Ajax call, so before that might need to use `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` instead of `WC()->cart->cart_contents_count` on that initial call? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

Comment: Yes I did see that as well...Still doesn't trigger the javascript though. It must be something in the logic, because the javascript triggers correctly without the IF statement

Comment: Might try separating out the conditions to narrow it down to one or the other. `if( $cart_num_products == $maximum_num_products) { <script>alert('max products')</script> }` etc.

Comment: I've tried using a simpler condition `if( is_woocommerce() == true) {` to see if that works, but it still doesnt trigger the javascript. Am I calling the condition in the right place? or should it be within the javascipt function?

Comment: The JS alert is inside a `$('body').on( 'added_to_cart'` event handler. If you want it to show an alert at other times, such as soon after page load, you'll need to add another event handler for that. I suspect there is another WooCommerce event such as `wc-composite-initializing` from https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/composite-products-js-api-reference/#section-6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171103/discussion-between-giuls-and-will-cain).